# Measurability and rectifiability

Tags: measure-theory

A set S is called k-rectifiable if it can be covered by a countable union of lipschitz images up to a set of measure zero, that is $H(S\setminus \cup f_i(S_i))=0$ for $f_i: S_i \subset \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is **any** measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ $k$-rectifiable? The intuition is that $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a smooth manifold of dimension k and I should be able to use the restriction of the diffeomorphisms as required maps.

Comment: I'm a little unsure of what you're asking, typically the definition of rectifiability requires a Borel set, but other than that restriction, every Borel subset of $\mathbb R^k$ is certainly $k$-rectifiable, as you can simply take $S_1=S$ and $f_1$ the identity.  There is absolutely no need to consider manifolds or more than one $f_i$.

Comment: I understand! Thank you. So am I right to say that this would imply that any k-purely unrectifiable set is not a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$, then?

Comment: No, it can still be a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^k$, it just would have to be an $\mathcal H^k$ nullset as well in that case.

Comment: Thank you!_____